# Webserver stopped writing to named pipe

Tags: linux, web-server, named-pipes

I am trying to debug a process which worked fine until about a week ago. I have a script accessible to my webserver which does nothing but write a value into an existing named pipe:

```
#!/bin/bash

pipe=/tmp/al_webui

echo 5 > $pipe
```

The script is called using sudo and the webserver may execute it by allowing it in `visudo`.

This has worked in the past but now nothing appears in the named pipe. If I execute the script manually the writing is successful, if the webserver calls it nothing happens. I do not receive any error message whatsoever. I can see the script being correctly called in my `/var/log/auth.log`:

```
Sep  4 12:22:30 luc sudo: www-data : TTY=unknown ; PWD=/srv/www/htdocs/al ; USER=root ; COMMAND=./al_webui_trigger.sh
Sep  4 12:22:30 luc sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Sep  4 12:22:30 luc sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
```

The log lists other script calls which are all successful (although they do not try to write to named pipes).

I have run out of ideas where to look since I get no errors of wrong filepaths or permissions (deliberate introduction of errors in the paths immediately show up the the `auth.log` and `chmod 777` does not change anything). Does someone have an idea how to proceed at this point?

I am running this on Debian Stretch and the errors may have started since I upgraded fom Jessie but I am not sure if this is connected.

Answer (score 0):

Turned out the PrivateTmp setting was the culprit, I assume this behaviour has changed during the upgrade. This means the webserver service was automatically associated with its private temp directory and therefore wrote to a different pipe than the one I was reading from. The solution is taken from [here](http://www.philipp-wagner.com/blog/2014/04/does-tmp-have-a-split-personality/):

```
mkdir /etc/systemd/system/apache2.service.d
echo -e "[Service]\nPrivateTmp=no" > /etc/systemd/system/apache2.service.d/privatetmp.conf
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl restart apache2
systemctl show apache | grep PrivateTmp
```

This creates a directory for a dedicated configuration used by the apache process. In the configuration file only one entry is listed which overwrites the value we have to change `PrivateTmp` and sets it to `false`. The rest reloads the systemctl daemon, restarts the webserver and checks whether the change was successful.

Please be aware of the security impacts a shared tmp-directory has before you decide if this is a suitable solution for you.